# C - What are C implementations?

Tags: c, implementation

Could you give me an explanation of what exactly an implementation is, taking inspiration from the three highlighted expressions?

From "C Primer Plus" > Language Standards

> **Currently, many C implementations are available.** Ideally, when you
>   write a C program, **it should work the same on any implementation**,
>   providing it doesn’t use machine-specific programming. For this to be
>   true in practice, **different implementations need to conform to a
>   recognized standard**.

Comment: Compilers innit, and the machines the compilers run on.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C_compilers

Comment: @Bathsheba well not just that libc is pretty much also part of the implementation

Comment: Basically, an implementation is the combination of a compiler and the C library it supports.

Comment: C language = what you type into a text editor; implementation = the thing that actually does something with what you typed.

Answer (score 8):

A standard conforming C implementation consists of a compiler that translates compilation units as mandated by the standard, an implementation of the standard library for all functions required by the standard and *something* (normally a linker) that puts everything together to build an executable file. In fact the implementation also includes all the software required to then run the produced executable.

We commonly speak of compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) when we should speak of C development environment. And inside each *vendor* system, you may have different implementations, because for example gcc or clang can generate executables for different int sizes (32 or 64 bits) and eventually different endiannesses. Each configuration then constitutes a specific implementation.

To be more exhaustive, it should be noted that support the standard library may be optional in so called *standalone execution environment* (by opposition to *hosted execution environment*). In real world, *standalone* mode is used for kernel development, because the kernel must be able to start before all the functions from the standard library are available. Else we would have a chicken and egg problem if the kernel required functions that it only can provide when it is fully loaded...

---

References: The draft n1570 for C11 defines an implementation as:

3.12
 implementation:
particular set of software, running in a particular translation environment under particular
control options, that performs translation of programs for, and supports execution of
functions in, a particular execution environment

Comment: Plus an operating system and hardware to run it on: A C implementation is **everything** needed to execute a program from C source code (defined in the C standard to include the translation environment and the execution environment, and the execution environment includes the operating system and the hardware).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: you are right. I shall soon update my answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — you’re describing a hosted implementation.  The are also free-standing implementations.  Granted, they’re rarer than hosted ones.

Comment: When you say that "In fact the implementation also includes all the software required to then run the produced executable", what are you referring to? because if I'm not mistaken an executable is a list of machine instructions, which element of this plan is part of the implementation of a C source? If for example I have a jpg, is the program I use to open it part of the C implementation?

Comment: Plus when my book says "Ideally, when you write a C program, it should work the same on any implementation", in this case, implementation stands for? Operating System? Processors? Or does it mean "it should compile the same on any implementation"?

Comment: @AlexQualcosa: I have given the reference from the standard in my answer. *It should work the same on any implementation* just means that the same C source code should have the same observable behaviour when compiled and run on different *systems*

Answer (score 2):

An implementation is an application to a particular specification.

For example, the specification could be the ISO international standard, and an implementation could be gcc or clang; the compilers that have implemented the standard specifications  coupled with an implementation of the standard library.

Comment: A C implementation includes not just a compiler but also the standard library -- both compile-time and runtime components.  This is particularly relevant to GCC, which provides only the compiler.  It needs to be paired with glibc to form a complete C implementation.

Answer (score 2):

C is typically implemented by a C compiler. In that paragraph you could simply replace this accordingly.

A reason for the more generic term "implementation" is that a compiler might contain multiple frontends or be made out of different tasks, or there are theoretically other forms than a compiler thinkable.

The C standard is defined against a "abstract machine" which behaves as the standard describes but doesn't have any other requirements and defines mapping to real machines as exercise for the implementor.

Comment: A C implementation includes not just a compiler but also a standard library -- both compile-time and runtime components.

Comment: while often a compiler (suite) includes those, but you are right of course and it's worth mentioning